# I'm getting a null pointer exception in addPointLoad() method

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I have 2 object classes that I am trying to access via this method, but it gives a null-pointer exception. Don't know if it is simply the array size or something more complicated. I was advised to increase the array size the following way (size x 1.5) but am clueless as to how can I do this.

Below is class Beam:

```
public abstract class Beam {
    private String name;
    protected double length; // [m]
    protected double Emod; // [MPa]
    protected double Ixx; // [m^4]
    private LoadModel loadModel;

    public Beam(String name, double length, double Emod, double Ixx) {
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.Emod = Emod;
        this.Ixx = Ixx;
    }
    public void addPointLoad(double magnitude, double loadPos) {
        PointLoad PL = new PointLoad(magnitude, loadPos);
        loadModel.addPL(PL);
    }
```

The LoadModel class is below:

```
public class LoadModel {
    private PointLoad[] pointLoads;
    private LineLoad[] lineLoads;
    public int plCounter;
    public int llCounter;

    public LoadModel(PointLoad[] pl, LineLoad[] ll) {
        pointLoads = new PointLoad[2];
        lineLoads = new LineLoad[2];
        plCounter = 0;
        llCounter = 0;
    }

    public void addPL(PointLoad pl) {
        if (plCounter < pointLoads.length) {
            pointLoads[plCounter] = pl;
            plCounter++;
        } else {
            plCounter++;
            pointLoads[plCounter] = pl;
            plCounter++;
        }
        System.out.println("The amount of Point Loads have been increased");
    }

    public int numPL() {  //Added this aswell as I want to keep track of the number of point loads
        return plCounter;
    }
```

Below is the PointLoad class:

```
public class PointLoad {
    private double magnitude;
    private double loadPos;
    
    public PointLoad(double magnitude, double loadPos) {
        this.magnitude = magnitude;
        this.loadPos = loadPos;
    }
    
    public double getMag() {
        return magnitude;
    }
    
    public double getLoadPos() {
        return loadPos;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any use of Ertag BEAM. Please remove the beam tag. Also, the load tag is for the load on the cpu, not physical loads. Please remove that tag also.

Comment: Could you add the exception output?

Comment: @NomadMaker sorry thought I was referring to structural beams and loads

Comment: @Moray I'm not sure what you're referring to I'm quite new to programming

Comment: @Arnaud I'll check that thanks

Comment: Since arrays cannot be resized programmatically, perhaps you could use a ListArray to store the elements rather than arrays.

Comment: The only thing that could cause NPE here is `loadModel` being `null`. And you didn't provide relevant code where it is initialized.

Comment: @NomadMaker I'll try that aswell thanks, though I'm not comfortable with ListArray with my current experience

Comment: @Amongalen Ok will check that thanks

Comment: @El_Chupacabra I mean the exception output you get

Comment: @Moray Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at _22751459.Beam.addPointLoad(Beam.java:54)
 at _22751459.TestBeam.main(TestBeam.java:7)

Comment: Which class is Beam.java? Is that the first or second code block in your question?

Comment: @Moray It's the super-class that contains all the info regarding the type of beam as well as it's length/Ixx/Emodulus, will add it as it may clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a member like

```
private LoadModel loadModel;
```

and then later you try to call its method like

```
loadModel.addPL(PL)
```

which fails due to [NullPointerException](https://blog.udemy.com/java-null-pointer-exception/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=udemyads&utm_campaign=DSA_Catchall_la.EN_cc.ROW&utm_content=deal4584&utm_term=_._ag_88010211481_._ad_455011610789_._kw__._de_c_._dm__._pl__._ti_dsa-449490803887_._li_20892_._pd__._&matchtype=b&gclid=Cj0KCQjwvvj5BRDkARIsAGD9vlJhIXjJJic0-DIy6990DoA0UJT8PYibqAMtLC-fqSqSwqEETGnKePEaAsJMEALw_wcB), because you cannot call a method of that which does not exist. So, to solve your actual problem, you need to initialize `loadModel` by calling the constructor of `LoadModel`.

You can instantly know whether the array size is the actual problem, because trying to refer to an element of an array outside of bounds will throw an [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), not a `NullPointerException`.

After you fix your NPE problem now, you might encounter other problems, but let's worry about them when they actually start to cause problems. You can "resize" an array by creating a new array of the desired size of the same type, initializing its elements as you will (by copying the elements of the source) and then assign the new array as the new value of your array variable.

Answer (score 1):

Add to Beam constructor this line:

loadModel = new LoadModel(null, null);

Comment: Will not work. LoadModel constructor takes parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Uhuh! Your `loadModel` reference seems to be null in the `Beam` class. You need to initialize that in either the `Beam's` constructor.

Comment: If I initialize it within a sub-class will that work as it's declared as a private attribute?

Comment: @El_Chupacabra it will not work, but you can create a public method that calls the constructor and initializes the member and then call that public method.